# Numpy iterating over rows

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

I kind of have the misconception that for loops should be avoided in Numpy for speed reasons, for example

```py
import numpy

a = numpy.array([[2,0,1,3],[0,2,3,1]])
targets = numpy.array([[1,1,1,1,1,1,1]])
output = numpy.zeros((2,1))
for i in range(2):
    output[i] = numpy.mean(targets[a[i]])
```

Is this a good way to get the mean on selected positions of each row? Feels like there might be ways to slice the array first then apply mean directly.

Comment: What does `targets[a]` look like?  Can you use the axis parameter of `np.mean`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
targets[a].mean(1)
```

Note that in your example, `targets` need to be 1-D and not 2-D. Otherwise, your loop throws out of bound index as it interprets the index for row index and not the column index.

Answer (score 1):

`numpy` actually interprets this for you: `targets[a]` works "row-wise" and subsequently using `np.mean(targets[a], axis=1)` as suggested by @hpaulj in the comments does exactly what you want:

```
import numpy

a = numpy.array([[2,0,1,3],[0,2,3,1]])
targets = numpy.arange(1,6) # To make the results differ
output = numpy.mean(targets[a], axis=1) # the i-th row of targets[a] is targets[a[i]]
```